# What does this error mean? 'Error: Unable to find a project reference for project configuration item'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, controller, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor and .NET and I am trying to follow a CRUD tutorial. I am trying to generate a API controller scaffold in Blazor. I name it SuperHeroController.cs and click build. It returns with:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(5,5): Error: Unable to find a project reference for project configuration item '/Users/myname/Projects/BlazorFullStackCrud/BlazorFullstackCrud/Client/BlazorFullstackCrud.Client.csproj' (BlazorFullstackCrud.Server)

I check the file in question: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets

And this is the problematic line of code although I don't understand why.

```
<MergeConfigurationProperties
  CandidateConfigurations="@(_ReferencedProjectsConfiguration)"
  ProjectReferences="@(_StaticWebAssetProjectReference)">
```

Can anyone explain why it is returning this error?

Comment: BlazorFullstackCrud.Client.csproj - this project is missing in your solution. Do you see it in your Solution Explorer in VS IDE ?

Comment: I don't think it's there how do you add the solution in this instance? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at the files you got from the tutorial, if that has folder with all files related to that .csproj, then you `Add -> Existing item` , and select this .csproj in your VStudio.

Comment: Ok, so I added it and it is now in my Solution Items folder but my controller still will not create, not sure why?

Comment: Is it giving the same error or different one, share details by editing your question.

Comment: Ok i have fixed it. The line <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorFullstackCrud.Client.csproj" /> wasn't inside my .Client.csproj file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to solve this question is to add

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorFullstackCrud.Client.csproj" />
```

into `.Client.csproj`.